# How to keep slides even when resizing swiper

Tags: css, swiper.js

In the desktop size, there is one slide in the middle and the other slides on the left and right.
And in mobile size, only one slide is visible.
No problem until here.

However, if I resize my browser to mobile size and then resize it to desktop size, I see 5 slides.
How can I keep it even if I resize it?

Please, anyone suggest to me.
https://codepen.io/lpla/pen/PoGRgVQ

**HTML**

```
<section class="main_section section_3">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide bg1">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide bg2">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide bg3">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide bg4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**SCSS**

```
.section_3 {
  padding-bottom: 160px; position: relative;
    .swiper-container { padding-top: 70px; }
    .swiper-slide {
    width: 62.5%; height: 545px; margin: 0; transition: all .3s; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 60px; position: relative;
    
    &.bg1 {
      background: url(https://dummyimage.com/1200x798/000/fff) no-repeat center/cover;
    }
    &.bg2 {
      background: url(https://dummyimage.com/1200x798/ddd/000e0e) no-repeat center/cover;
    }
    &.bg3 {
      background: url(https://dummyimage.com/1200x798/e0e/fff) no-repeat center/cover;
    }
    &.bg4 {
      background: url(https://dummyimage.com/1200x798/283d0e/4ff0f0) no-repeat center/cover;
    }
        &:not(.swiper-slide-active) { opacity: 0.5; }
        &.swiper-slide-active { position: relative; margin-top: -70px; }
        img { width: 100%; }
    }
}
```

JS

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.section_3 .swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 0,
  speed: 700,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  breakpoints: {
    1280: {
      slidesPerView: '2',
      centeredSlides: false
    },
    960: {
      slidesPerView: '1',
      centeredSlides: false
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The cause of the error was slidesPerView:'auto'.
I did some code fix, such as entering a number instead of auto and changing the margin to javscript.

**JS**

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.section_3 .swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 2,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  speed: 700,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  breakpoints: {
    1280: {
      // slidesPerView: '2',
      // centeredSlides: false,
                // slidesPerView: 2
    },
    960: {
      // slidesPerView: '1',
      centeredSlides: false,
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 0
    }
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/lpla/pen/yLaKdeg